SFMC Filter users by Sent Email Name
I would like to know if it's possible to Grab all users who have received an email based on the Email Name sent, not JOBID. I've tried JS inside an automation, but for some reason, it does not populate the DE.
Any alternative method in SQL will be much appreciated thanks!
I have a send log DE called SendJobs that has all the info about the all sends like JobID, From Name, EmailName, SchedTime etc.
Thanks in advance.

the _JOB dataview has emailname which you can use by joining _job to your sendlog on jobid
